# PCL 1.8.1 crash on cloud delete after StatisticalOutliersRemoval

Tags: memory, eigen, point-cloud-library

I have an application which is build using several DLL files.
I'm trying to perform PCL's statistical outliers removal using the following code:

```
    PointCloudWithRGBNormalsPtr pclCloud(new PointCloudWithRGBNormals());

    ConvertPointCloudToPCL(in_out_cloud /*my own structure which includes xyz, rgb, nx ny nz*/, *pclCloud);

    pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<PointXYZRGBNormal> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud(pclCloud);
    sor.setMeanK(10);
    sor.setStddevMulThresh(1.0);
    sor.filter(*pclCloud);
```

`ConvertPointCloudToPCL`:

```
static void ConvertPointCloudToPCL(const std::vector<Cloud3DrgbN> &in, PointCloudWithRGBNormals &output)
{
    for (auto it = in.begin(); it != in.end(); it++)
    {
        const Cloud3DrgbN &p3d = *it;;
        PointXYZRGBNormal p;
        p.x = p3d.x;
        p.y = p3d.y;
        p.z = p3d.z;
        p.normal_x = p3d.nX;
        p.normal_y = p3d.nY;
        p.normal_z = p3d.nZ;
        p.r = p3d.r;
        p.g = p3d.g;
        p.b = p3d.b;
        output.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

For some reason, if I call this function from 1 of my dlls it works as it should. However, there's 1 dll that if I call it from it, when `pclCloud` goes out of scope, I'm getting an exception from `Eigen`'s `Memory.h` file at the `handmade_aligned_free` function

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit, pcl 1.8.1 and Eigen 3.3 (tried 3.3.4, same thing)

**Update**:

After further digging, I've found that `EIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED` was set to 0 because I'm using `AVX2` in my "problematic" DLL. I'm still not sure though why using Eigen's "handmade" aligned malloc/free causes this crash.

There seems to be a known issue (see [this](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1791)) with Eigen, PCL & AVX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found the problem and how to solve it.

It seems that the DLLs that comes with the "All in 1 installer" for windows weren't compiled with `AVX/AVX2` support.

When linking these libraries with my own DLLs, the ones that compiled using the `AVX`, this mismatch caused `Eigen` to use the different types of allocations and freeing of memory causing the crash.

I compiled PCL from source using `AVX2` and linked these library and everything works.

It's worth mentioning that the DLL that worked before now has issues since it doesn't have AVX and PCL now do.